# Retrofit throwing path must not be null error during first call

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

im facing an issue where Retrofit is throwing the following error:

`Path parameter "boid" value must not be null. (parameter #1)`

I have checked the values, and it is all correctly specified.
And this error only occurs during the first Retrofit call, if i made the same API call again the second time, then its fine.
The code is as following:

```
@POST("v4.0/orderdata/{"+ Key.RANDOM_PATH +"} ")
Observable<ApiResponse> postBody(@Path(Endpoints.Key.RANDOM_PATH ) String path,
                                 @Header(Endpoints.Header.h1) String h1,
                                 @Header(Endpoints.Key.h2) int h2,
                                 @Body PostBody postBody);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  @POST("v4.0/orderdata/{path}")
Observable<ApiResponse> postBody(@Path("path") String path,
                                 @Header(Endpoints.Header.h1) String h1,
                                 @Header(Endpoints.Key.h2) int h2,
                                 @Body PostBody postBody);
```

It should be like this and pass the value of `Key.RANDOM_PATH` in `path` param

Comment: im sure thats not the issue, the api works if i call it the second time.